# xAxis title and lables does not appear in CorePlot

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-plot

I am trying display some data on a chart using CorePlot. The y axis title and the labels get displayed without an issue, however the title of the x axis and the tick labels does not get displayed even with the automatic labeling policy. Please help me.

```
 CPTMutableLineStyle *whiteLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    whiteLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor whiteColor];
    whiteLineStyle.lineWidth = 1.0;

    CPTXYGraph *newGraph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    newGraph.paddingRight = 50;
    newGraph.paddingLeft  = 50;
    newGraph.paddingTop = 10;
    newGraph.paddingBottom = 40;
    newGraph.plotAreaFrame.paddingBottom = 40;
    newGraph.plotAreaFrame.masksToBorder = NO;
    newGraph.plotAreaFrame.borderLineStyle = nil;

    self.graphHost.hostedGraph = newGraph;

    CPTTheme *theme  = [CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTSlateTheme];
    [newGraph applyTheme:theme];

    CPTXYAxisSet *xyAxisSet= (CPTXYAxisSet *)newGraph.axisSet;
    CPTXYAxis *xAxis = xyAxisSet.xAxis;
    CPTXYAxis *yAxis = xyAxisSet.yAxis;

    xAxis.title = @"Date / Time";
    yAxis.title = @"Trading Range";

    [xAxis setLabelingPolicy:CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone];
    xAxis.majorTickLocations = [self majorTickLocations];
    [xAxis setAxisLabels:[NSSet setWithArray:[self getXAxisTitleArray]]];
    xAxis.majorTickLineStyle = whiteLineStyle;



    [yAxis setLabelingPolicy:CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic];

    CPTTradingRangePlot *ohlcPlot = [[CPTTradingRangePlot alloc] initWithFrame:newGraph.bounds];
    ohlcPlot.labelOffset = 10.0;
    ohlcPlot.stickLength = 10.0;
    ohlcPlot.dataSource = self;
    ohlcPlot.plotStyle  = CPTTradingRangePlotStyleCandleStick;
    ohlcPlot.lineStyle  = whiteLineStyle;

    CPTMutableTextStyle *whiteTextStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
    whiteTextStyle.color = [CPTColor whiteColor];
    whiteTextStyle.fontSize = 10.0;
    ohlcPlot.labelTextStyle = whiteTextStyle;

    CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *) newGraph.defaultPlotSpace;
    [newGraph addPlot:ohlcPlot toPlotSpace:plotSpace];
```

Comment: Maybe they are cut off; try smaller values for `paddingBottom`.

Comment: tried it , no luck :(

Comment: You probably need *larger* bottom padding and/or smaller label and title offsets. Also, check the text style. If you're not using the same one as the y-axis labels that work, try that temporarily as a test.

Comment: If I change  the  bottom padding values to newGraph.paddingBottom = 300;,newGraph.plotAreaFrame.paddingBottom =300; then I cold see the lablels , however then the chart goes off the screen . Any ideas welcome

Answer (score 0):

The following code solved my problem:

```
xAxis.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:0.0];
```